# When using react to make web (sites, pages or applications) how do you decide between JavaScript, TypeScript or JavaScriptXML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

So the thing is, I have completed a design of my portfolio and an eCommerce website using `Figma` and recently pick up `React` and `Tailwind` using `Vite`. I have no problem with basic JavaScript. But what I want to know is how do you decide which to use between basic `JavaScript .js, JavascriptXML .jsx` and `TypeScript .ts`. Most `React` tutorials using `Vite` use `.jsx` what I understand is that `.jsx` was designed or introduced to solve the problem of `.js` not being able to run in an `HTML` template and `.ts` is advanced `.js` that is preferred by web developers because you don't get bugs or errors when deploying the website or application.
But how and when do you decide when to use what I'm confused.

Also are there best practices to which languages you should, use and which are a good and bad match. Any explanation involving `React, JavaScript, TypeScript, JSX, HTML` and `Node` will be highly apricated. Anything will be appreciated, no matter how insignificant you think it may be, it will aid me on my web development journey.

Comment: The answer is ...
...
...
it depends

Comment: One of the things it will depend on is what the standard way of doing things is for whatever team/project you are working with at the time.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is an extension off the JavaScript language that originated from JavaScript's shortcomings, dealing with types. This [TypeScript page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/why-create-typescript) explains some things. JSX is used because it allows for auto-completions designed *specifically for React templates*. Same thing with TSX.